# SQR report generate pdf space issue

Tags: sqr

I have faced one issue during pdf generation.

there is two section of report.
1.details of the id
2.total for an id

for example:

id  name  total_fee  total_earing           date
1   test  11111      55555                 05/05/2014
1   test  22222      44444                05/05/2014

### id 1

total_fee      33333 
  total earning  99999

in my pdf generation total section (section 2) should come in next page if and only if the space is not available to print the entire section 2 in same page.

i have used:

new-page  !need some logic to check id space available on above page if yes then !print above
print id $id
print total_fee
print  toteal_earning

Please assist.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you provide a sample of what you have tried, and clear output of what is happening now, and what you want to happen?

Comment: sure!  for example:if we are generating a report for a summary report on the school fee details. so 1 section is containg the all details like below:             roll_number name fee_paid date

Comment: You will need to know how many lines are in the detail ahead of time.  Perhaps look up in the SQR manual the command NEXT-LISTING and use the NEED parm.  However, its parameter is a constant and not a variable.  This will work mainly if your summary is variable.  So if you know that detail needs at least 40 lines, you could specify NEXT-LISTING NEED=40.  Your other option is to keep a separate count and page manually using NEW-PAGE.  So track how many lines on a page and then if summary plus detail lines would exceed the page count, do a page before printing the details.